# Body-swapped racist learns about tolerance

Tags: story-identification, movie

I have a vague memory of a film, probably from the 1960s. The main character (an older, slightly overweight white man) living in the Deep South is magically(?) turned into an African American. He experiences intolerance and, as a result, learns that racism is a bad thing.

There was singing and dancing (in a style reminiscent of a Disney film) and several other characters also dancing with him.

Notably the main character was just put in black pancake makeup for his transformation. It wasn't very convincing.

Comment: Not [Soul Man](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_Man_(film))

Comment: For a moment there I confused the titles of Soul Man and Watermelon Man.  It happens to me in cases of extreme caffeine deprivation.

Comment: Just for the sake of reference, https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ColorMeBlack

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I didn't see any there (either in Film or TV) that were of the right time frame and had musical numbers.

Comment: not sure if this is the film you're referring to but a Twilight Zone episode had exactly that; a loud, overweight white man bellyaching loudly about blacks......when he leaves the bar, he finds he is viewed as black and subject to all of the prejudices that he himself has previously exhibited.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4N3Tl0YT6w0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah, the late 1960's, when Hollywood thought it could still get away with blackface if it was under the guise of social commentary. There are a depressing number of such movies.

Since you mentioned singing and dancing, and posted in a SFF exchange, I thought it was necessary to mention the 1968 musical

### Finian's Rainbow

Based on a hit 1947 Broadway musical by Burton Lane and E.Y. Harburg, the movie was one of Francis Ford Coppola's first directoral efforts.

[image]

Finian McLonergan (played by Fred Astaire, in his final movie role), accompanied by his daughter, Sharon (Petula Clark), emigrate from Ireland to the village of Rainbow Valley, Missitucky.

What Finian didn't tell Sharon was that he brought with him a pot of gold he'd stolen from a leprechaun back in Ireland. This leprechaun, Og (Tommy Steele), follows Finian to America to get his gold back. Finian hides the gold but local mute girl Susan (Barbara Hancock) finds it and moves it.

The American Dream yields to the American Reality as Finian and Sharon encounter the plight of local sharecroppers under bigoted Senator Billboard Rawkins (Keenan Wynn).

At one point, Sharon gets so angry at Rawkins that she says to Rawkins

> There's something wrong with the world that you and your kind have made for people like Henry! I wish you could know what that world is like. I wish to God you were black!

She happened to have been standing over the spot where Susan had hidden the pot of gold. Guess what happens next.

After Rawkins' change, a witch hunt for Sharon begins. Eventually Og, who has fallen for Susan, uses the pot of gold's final wish to turn Rawkins back.  Even though this means the pot of gold is no longer magical, and Og is now mortal again.

The musical was part of [this other answer of mine](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/whence-comes-the-association-of-leprechauns-with-rainbows/5350#5350) over on Mythology SE.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly [Watermelon Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watermelon_Man_(film)), 1970.

From Criterion:

> Melvin Van Peebles’s only foray into Hollywood filmmaking, Watermelon
> Man is one of the most audacious, radically conceived works to be
> financed by a major American studio in the 1970s. Comedian Godfrey
> Cambridge delivers a virtuoso performance (initially in whiteface) as
> Jeff Gerber, a loudmouthed, bigoted white insurance salesman whose
> sitcomlike suburban existence is jarringly upended when he wakes up to
> discover, in a wild spin on Franz Kafka’s The Metamorphosis, that he
> has become a Black man. What ensues is a ferocious satire of society’s
> racist double standards that gradually transforms into an empowering
> portrait of awakening Black consciousness, executed with a mix of
> acerbic irreverence and deadly serious political commentary by a
> relentlessly subversive Van Peebles.

From Wikipedia:

> Watermelon Man is a 1970 American comedy film directed by Melvin Van
> Peebles and starring Godfrey Cambridge, Estelle Parsons, Howard Caine,
> D'Urville Martin, Kay Kimberley, Mantan Moreland, and Erin Moran.
> Written by Herman Raucher, it tells the story of an extremely bigoted
> 1960s-era white insurance salesman named Jeff Gerber, who wakes up one
> morning to find that he has become black. The premise for the film was
> inspired by Franz Kafka's Metamorphosis, and by John Howard Griffin's
> autobiographical Black Like Me.

It's on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE2CFeKYXhY).

Comment: My first thought too, although I don't remember any song-and-dance numbers. Also, it's his "whiteface" depiction which is a bit uncanny value.

Comment: A similar theme, but the character was definitely a white guy in black makeup, not a black guy in whiteface

Answer (score 1):

[Black Like Me](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057889/), 1964, has [James Whitmore](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0926235/?ref_=tt_cl_t_1) in [dark makeup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTJDWPIy2eo).

[image]

Comment: No, this isn't like it at all. Theres no signing and dancing and the race change isn't fantastical

Comment: Black Like Me didn't have a magical transformation -- the character deliberately painted himself black to experience it.